# Swift: how to use Scroll View when there are many data to show

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview

In one of my application's view I want to display tasks details according to their fields like: object/title, content, notes, status...and so on. Many of these fields, overall title and content, may be very long meaning that they can consist in a long text to show. In the storyboard it is easy to insert labels and text fields to fill in but I wonder how I can handle them when their content is very long and overcome the screen size and so a scrolling action is required.
So, how can I implement all this? Is a Scroll View (from the XCode library) supposed to be used? And finally, if I have many fields to show but there isn't enough "space" in the storyboard when I am building the UI, how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good time for a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView`. They are both subclasses of `UIScrollView` and they are designed to solve the issue you're facing.

Research their `delegate` and `dataSource` protocols to find what you're looking for.

Comment: But if I use a one of those classes, for example UITableView, then the cells will automatically be resized according to their content in order to show it all? For example a long text...

Comment: Moreover their content should be editable when the button Edit is tapped and I need to inser buttoms too...maybe is it better to use UICollectionView?

Comment: `UICollectionView` is the most flexible, yes. It is slightly more complicated than `UITableView` to get working, but there are plenty of tutorials online.